# Tensorflow - Cannot save an unrolled RNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using a GRU RNN model that i want to unroll for deployment purpose:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.models.Sequential(name="KWS")
model.add(keras.Input(shape=(30,13)))
model.add(keras.layers.GRU(30, activation='linear', name='GRU_layer', unroll=True))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu', name='dense_1'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output'))
model.compile('rmsprop','mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

# [training]
```

When i try to save it:

```py
model.save('/temp/', save_format='tf')
```

It produce this error:

```
ValueError: Unrolling requires a fixed number of timesteps.
```

I can't figure it out.